# Is there any cms kind of plugin to connect a static website?

Tags: plugins, web, content-management-system

Our website doesn't have any backend. It's a simple static site. Now we want to create a Press release section where content needs to be updated on regular basis by Company PR itself. Is there any plugin available to achieve this? We don't want to move to any CMS as of now.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend having a look at jocms. Its still in beta state but might fit to your problem.

[jocms website](http://jocms.rusciori.org/en)

another option would be sitecake. does basically the same but is not for free

[sitecake website](http://sitecake.com/)